# Rails - update email to Devise User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have the following profile_controller's action:

```
def update
  updated = if _profile_params[:password].present?
    current_user.skip_confirmation!
    current_user.update_with_password(_profile_params)
  else
    current_user.skip_confirmation!
    current_user.update(_profile_params)
  end

  if updated
    render json: ProfilePresenter::Public.new(current_user)
  else
    render status: :unprocessable_entity,
         json: Oj.dump({ errors: current_user.errors.messages })
  end
end
```

If I PUT to the controller the following payload:

```
{"first_name":"Aieie", "phone": "+393345678909", "email": "example@gmail.com"}
```

The system generates a confirmation email, even though I used `skip_confirmation!` to skip it.

How can I avoid the system to send the confirmation email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are calling it while updating and before save, you need to do:

```
current_user.skip_reconfirmation!
```

remember `skip_reconfirmation!`

Answer (score 0):

ok, it was an easy one. Just use `.skip_reconfirmation!` ([doc](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FModels%2FConfirmable%3Askip_reconfirmation!))